# Lock Free Bounded Stack C++11 atomics

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stack, lock-free

I was thinking about using very basic bounded (preallocated) stack to keep track of my threads ids in correct LIFO order. So i was wondering if my implementation is thread safe:

```
// we use maximum 8 workers
size_t idle_ids_stack[8];
// position current write happening at
std::atomic_uint_fast8_t idle_pos(0);

// this function is called by each thread when it is about to sleep
void register_idle(size_t thread_id) 
{
    std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release);
    idle_ids_stack[idle_pos.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed)] = thread_id;
}

// this function can be called from anywhere at anytime
void wakeup_one() 
{
    uint_fast8_t old_pos(idle_pos.load(std::memory_order_relaxed));
    std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
    size_t id;
    do
    {
        if(old_pos == 0) return; // no idle threads in stack; exit;
        id = idle_ids_stack[old_pos-1];
    }
    while (!idle_pos.compare_exchange_weak(old_pos, old_pos-1, std::memory_order_acquire, std::memory_order_relaxed));
    // wakeup single thread
    signal_thread(id);
}
```

Comment: This might fit Code Review a bit more...

Comment: You should rarely ever use fences. Synchronize on the atomic variables directly.

Comment: You may want to use some testing tool, e.g: http://www.1024cores.net/home/relacy-race-detector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not an expert in lock free programming, but I'm pretty sure that your code is NOT thread safe.

1. Let's first look at `register_idle()`:

   What could happen here is that Thread1 increments `idle_pos` but before it stores its id, another thread calls `wakeup_once` and uses an outdated id (in the worst case even an invalid on, because the array is not yet initialized). Also I don't see the reason for the memory fence.
2. In `wakeup_one()` you have a similar Problem (called [ABA problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABA_problem)) :

   - You load the current `idle_pos` and according `id`.
   - Another thread calls and completes `wakeup_one` (idle_pos is decreased).
   - Yet another thread calls `register_idle` , which increases idle_pos again to the same value as before.
   - Now the first thread resumes, thinks `idle_pos` is unchanged and signals the wrong thread

I might be mistaken, but I believe it is in general not possible to create completely lock free stack based on an array, because you have to do two things in a single atomic operation: modify the index variable and store or load the value in the array.

Aside from those logic errors, I'd highly recommend not to use stand alone memory fences (they make the code less readable and might even be more costly). Also I would only start to manually specify memory orders, after I made sure that the program is correct with the default ones.